# Javascript condition on name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this code to say "hello" to normal people, but if your name is Nick, I want it to say, "Hello Master, You Have Pressed (whatever button you pressed)." But it is not working, I'm not sure whats wrong, here's the code that I'm trying to use.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Name(button)
{
    ame = prompt("Whats Your Name?", "Visitor")
    var ame = "Nick"
    if(ame == "Nick"){
        alert("Hello Master, You Have Pressed, " + button)
    }else(ame != "Nick")
        alert("Hello " + ame + ", You Pressed " + button)
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:Name('1')"><img src="1.gif"></a>
<a href="javascript:Name('2')"><img src="2.gif"></a>
<a href="javascript:Name('3')"><img src="3.gif"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing semicolons at the end of statements!

Comment: @siidheesh Javascript doesn't require them.

Comment: Try to give questions titles that describe the problem, not you. You should also keep the JavaScript console open so you'll see the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one issue i see right away is your using `ame` before it's even declared.

```
function Name(button) {
    var ame = prompt("Whats Your Name?", "Visitor");

    if (ame == "Nick") {
        alert("Hello Master, You Have Pressed, " + button);
    }
    else {
        alert("Hello " + ame + ", You Pressed " + button);
    }
}
```

there were a couple extra syntax issue but I believe this should work.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

There is no conditional statement with else.

Read up on [if/else on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 2):

```
}else(ame != "Nick")
```

should be

```
}else if(ame != "Nick"){
```

or just

```
}else{
```